How does mmap'ed eBPF map shared between processes synchronizes operations?
It's possible to mmap eBPF map of type BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY. I have a configuration where multiple processes access this mmaped map that contains entries of type "some cacheline-sized struct" in both kernel-space and user-space:

Kernel-space modifies this map by using libbpf's bpf_map_update_elem
User-space processes access map's values by reading value stored in previously mmaped pointer

How are this accesses threadsafe? Is there some kind of per-map mutex or fine-grained locking involved? Is there any hidden cost (like TLB cache-misses??) involved? What additional cost do both operations (kernel-update and user-read) have because of synchronization?

To the best of my knowledge this access can't be threadsafe. We have primitives for locking when two BPF programs access the same map value. And there exists locking on the map level for both the helpers and syscall interface. But when you mmap the memory of an arraymap into userspace access to that memory bypasses the lock normally used for the helpers and syscall interface.
You might be able to implement some form of lock yourself using a CMPXCHG instruction to implement a crude mutex.
In the end the mmap feature is intended to map global variables into userspace for casual use (test results, infrequently accessed settings). For anything requiring atomic updates, its better to use the syscall interface and locking primitives

shouldn't ebpf array be just extremely low overhead and an actual simple array? for example, ebpf array doesn't support bpf_map_update_elem operation with flag BPF_NOEXIST, because it doesn't make sense to element to not exist in array, so i think there is no additional data stored per each cell of an array? i don't know actually :(

Yes, you are right, took a look at the code. Arraymaps unlike hashmaps have no builtin RCU to prevent concurrent modification from the syscall interface and BPF, I thought this was the case. The only mechanism to do this is with spinlocks https://lwn.net/Articles/779120/
You make a spinlock struct part of your value, you can take the lock with helpers from BPF side and you can use the BPF_F_LOCK flag when doing lookups/updates from userspace to take the lock before doing the read/write. Unfortunately, spinlocks are not compatible with mmap on certain kernel versions as far as I know.

that's sad :(. however, how does mmap with MAP_SHARED ensure correct concurrently modified values: does it pagefault page on each core after write operation?

I honestly don't know. The BPF code calls into the shared mmap code to remap the arraymap pages, so I would assume it works the same as "normal" shared memory, but can't say that conclusively
